# Convert JSON to dictionary in swift 3 for uplaod image from facebook to firebase

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to upload my profile picture from facebook to firebase and then want to retrieve...
my code was working well in swift 2.0 i-e

```
let urlPic = (data?.objectForKey("url"))! as! String
```

when I convert it to swift 3.0 i-e

`let urlPic = ((data as AnyObject).object("url"))! as! String`

**There is an error**

> *Cannot call Value of non-function type 'Any?!'*

There is my complete code please help...

```
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
        // User is signed in.

        let name = user.displayName
        let photoUrl = user.photoURL
        let uid = user.uid


        self.username.text = name

        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: photoUrl!)
        self.profilepic.image = UIImage(data: data!)

        //------Saving in DB-----

        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()

        let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "my storage_url..")
        let profilePicRef = storageRef.child(user.uid+"/userPic.jpg")


        profilePicRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {

                print("Unable to download the image")

            } else {

                if (data != nil)
                {
                    self.profilepic.image = UIImage(data:data!)

                }
            }
        }

if (profilepic.image == nil)

        {  var profilepic = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/picture", parameters: ["height":300 ,"width":300, "redirect": false], httpMethod: "GET")
            profilepic?.start(completionHandler: {(connection, result, error) -> Void in

                if error == nil {

                    let dictionary = result as? NSDictionary
                    let data = dictionary?.object(forKey: "data")

                    let urlPic = ((data as AnyObject).object("url"))! as! String
                    if let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:urlPic)!) {

                        let profilePicRef = storageRef.child(user.uid+"/userPic.jpg")
                        let uploadTask = profilePicRef.putData(imageData, metadata:nil){

                            metadata, error in
                            if( error == nil){

                                let downloadUrl = metadata!.downloadURL
                            }
                            else { print("Error in downloading image") }
                        }
                self.profilepic.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    }
                }
            })
        }

    } else {
        // No user is signed in.
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

In Swift use native `Dictionary` instead of `NSDictionary` and instead of `object(forKey:)` use `subscript` with Dictionary, so instead of casting `result` to `NSDictionary` cast it to `[String:Any]`.

```
if error == nil {
    if let dictionary = result as? [String:Any], 
       let dataDic = dictionary["data"] as? [String:Any],
       let urlPic = dataDic["url"] as? String {
          //access urlPic here
    }
}
```

**Note:** In swift 3 use native [`Data`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data) and [`URL`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/url) instead of `NSData` and `NSURL`.